# Elasticsearch7.x plug-in failed to load local so library file。

Tags: java, elasticsearch, centos7, elasticsearch-plugin

I developed an analyzer plug-in. The plug-in uses a C language so library file, but when I call the plug-in word segmentation, the local library link fails.

```
Caused by: 
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:   
 com.***.JNIWrapper.seg_segment(Ljava/lang/String;IZZLjava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

Caused by: 
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: failed to analyze;
```

I've tried the following in the plugin's plugin-security.policy file:

```
grant codeBase 
   "/opt/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.1.0/plugins/analysis-plugin/plugin.jar" 
    {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getProtectionDomain";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
    permission java.io.FilePermission
    "/opt/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.1.0/plugins/analysis-     
     plugin/Linux-amd64-64/lib.so", "read";
   };
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Correct plugin-security.policy file content
grant codeBase "file:/opt/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.1.0/plugins/analysis-plugin/plugin.jar" { permission java.security.AllPermission; permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader"; permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getProtectionDomain"; permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader"; permission java.io.FilePermission "/opt/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.1.0/plugins/analysis-plugin/Linux-amd64-64/lib.so", " read"; };

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by "AccessController.doPrivileged" and thank you guys.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).